# setting database for xp:dominoDocument via properties file

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I would like to set the location of a database for the xp:dominoDocument data Property via SSJS and a properties file:

```
<xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" action="openDocument"
            formName="album   -   $f-album" computeWithForm="both"
            concurrencyMode="force"
            databaseName="#{javascript:datasource.getString('DB_FILEPATH')}">
            <xp:this.documentId><![CDATA[#{javascript:context.getUrlParameter("UNID")}]]></xp:this.documentId>
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
```

The datasource property contains e.g.

```
DB_FILEPATH=Bildr6Phase10Data.nsf
```

and is available via

```
<xp:this.resources>
        <xp:bundle src="/datasource.properties" var="datasource"></xp:bundle>
    </xp:this.resources>
```

The code above will cast the error:

```
com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
Script interpreter error, line=1, col=12: [ReferenceError] 'datasource' not found
```

However if I try:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"
        value="#{javascript:datasource.getString('DB_FILEPATH')}">
    </xp:text>
```

I get the value from the property. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does EL '${datasource.DB_FILEPATH}' work?

Comment: I think it should be datasource.getString['DB_FILEPATH'] with brackets instead of paranthesis. And maybe you should rename your bundle name as it isn't unique to the database SSJS object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a Computed Field, try logging `datasource.getString('DB_FILEPATH')` in beforePageLoad and beforeRenderResponse. Also log out a message in `databaseName` property. I would expect the `databaseName` property to be required when the component tree is first loaded. However, I would not be surprised if the resource string is loaded later.

An alternative may be to use xsp.properties file. There is code on how to retrieve a property from xsp.properties in XPages OpenLog Logger.

Comment: I am now using a managed bean and calling the getFilepath method. There seems not to be any problems via this way. Not sure why.